# Sound not working after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, sound, alsa

After a routine upgrade of Xubuntu 15.10 sound stopped working. These steps didn't help, so the question is not a duplicate. Please help. Thank you.

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base  
sudo apt-get --reinstall install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`  
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio  
sudo alsa force-reload  

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio  
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio  
sudo alsa force-reload  

alsamixer  

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  

$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          200704  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_ca0132    57344  1
snd_hda_intel          36864  4
snd_hda_codec         135168  3
snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd_hda_core           65536  4  
snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  7
  snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,sn    d_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  20  snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
```

soundcore              16384  1 snd

Comment: What sound card ? purging and re-installing is extremely unlikely to solve anything see - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Comment: I've tried, but I got stuck at   sudo modprobe snd-[NAME OF YOUR SOUNDCARD'S DRIVER]

Answer (score 0):

```
lspci | grep "Audio"
```

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

```
sudo aplay -l
```

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: output devices shows "line out(plugged in)" and shows changing sound level when I play youtube music. But there is no sound...

Comment: 00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
stepanl@xubuntu15:~$